# Why is my background color not filling all of my table?

Tags: html, css, tablerow

I'm having a problem with an image within my table row.  For some reason, the background color will not extend and fill the table row in when I have a picture floating to the left.

```css
p.more {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
img.more {
  float: left !important;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  width: 330px;
}
span.more {
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
span.moreweelove {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="more">
        <a href="http://blog.weespring.com/weelove-littlehipsqueaks-knotted-headbands/">
          <img class="more" src="http://www.weespring.com/media/weelove_littlehipsqueeks.jpg">
        </a>
        <br>
        <span class="more"><span class="moreweelove"><strong>Modern, Comfy, and Fun Staples</strong></span></span>
      </p>
      <p class="readmore">
        <strong class="subheading">BIG LOVE FOR JUNE &amp; JANUARY</strong>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://blog.weespring.com/weelove-littlehipsqueaks-knotted-headbands/">
          <img src="http://www.weespring.com/media/read-more.png">
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>

      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you applied the color to the CONTENTS of the cell, so only where the `<p>` is will there be bg color. you should apply the color to the containing `<td>` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much to all.  I'm pretty new to tables and coding in general so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If want to fullfill an entire row with a background-color, youu should apply a css style to the corresponding `< tr >` tag.

Comment: Well, almost. If the table consists of more than one row, that way you'd see a gap between the rows. see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ou1mfey2/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you applied the background color the `<p>`, only the `<p>` itself will get colored. If the last line doesn't take up the full width of the container, e.g.

```
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

then only the parts with the `x` will get the background treatment. But if you apply the color to the containing `<td>`, which surrounds the paragraph, like so:

```
    +------------------------+
    |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
    |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
    |xxxxxxxxxxxxx           |
    +------------------------+
```

Then that final partial line will ALSO be colored, because the entire box of the `<td>` is colored, not just where the text is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're giving style to "p.more" not to the table. 
Try giving the background color to the table.